# Setting up redis a session handler for php with docker-compose

Tags: php, docker, redis, docker-compose

I thought redis would bind to my php container in the redis conf, but it fails with:

```
# Creating Server TCP listening socket phpfpm:6379: bind: Address not available
```

If I do localhost the session cache isn't working. I assume because the connection is being refused by the redis server. I'm looking for what needs to be in the redis.conf file and in the php.ini file. Here's what I thought it should be:

#### php.ini

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://redis:6379"
```

#### redis.conf

```
bind localhost phpfpm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if I understood your question well...

That happened to me when I had a network problem, can you put an example of your .YML configuration?

```
php:
    image: php:7.1-fpm-alpine
    #build: php
    networks:
      - internal_network
    volumes:
      - ../html:/var/www/html
    restart: always
redis:
    image: redis:4-alpine
    environment:
      #- REDIS_PASSWORD=${REDIS_PASSWORD}
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=YOUR_REDIS_PASSWORD
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    volumes:
      - ../data/redis:/data
    networks:
      - internal_network
nginx:
    image: nginx:1-alpine
    ports:   #only if traefik is disabled
     - 80:80 #only if traefik is disabled
    volumes:
     - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
     - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
     - ../html:/var/www/html
    networks:
     - internal_network
     - external_network
```

Is the extension already installed? do you use the build command?

> ./php/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine

RUN echo http://dl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community/ >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk add --no-cache shadow curl vim zlib-dev autoconf g++ make re2c \
    && pecl install -o -f redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis.so \
    && pecl clear-cache
```

You do not need anything else.
Your redis must be within a docker network, not exposed to the internet

[Link to conf](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf)

> By default, if no "bind" configuration directive is specified, Redis
>   listens  for connections from all the network interfaces available on
>   the server.  It is possible to listen to just one or multiple selected
>   interfaces using  the "bind" configuration directive, followed by one
>   or more IP addresses.
>
> Examples:
>
> bind 192.168.1.100 10.0.0.1  bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
>
> ~~~ WARNING ~~~ If the computer running Redis is directly exposed to
>   the  internet, binding to all the interfaces is dangerous and will
>   expose the  instance to everybody on the internet. So by default we
>   uncomment the  following bind directive, that will force Redis to
>   listen only into  the IPv4 lookback interface address (this means
>   Redis will be able to  accept connections only from clients running
>   into the same computer it  is running).
>
> IF YOU ARE SURE YOU WANT YOUR INSTANCE TO LISTEN TO ALL THE
>   INTERFACES  JUST COMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE. 
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   bind 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks nasatome. Turned out to be a dumb mistake on my part. I thought I had the php extension installed but when I looked at my Dockerfile, I found I had commented it out some time back.

Comment: ./php/Dockerfile - fails with the below error.

WARNING: Ignoring http://dl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz: No such file or directory
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  shadow (missing):
    required by: world[shadow]
The command '/bin/sh -c echo http://dl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community/ >> /etc/apk/repositories     && apk add --no-cache shadow curl vim zlib-dev autoconf g++ make re2c     && pecl install -o -f redis     && docker-php-ext-enable redis.so     && pecl clear-cache' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: This is the right one now:

FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine

RUN echo http://uk.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community/  >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk add --no-cache shadow curl vim zlib-dev autoconf g++ make re2c \
    && pecl install -o -f redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis.so \
    && pecl clear-cache